# Windows: Only allow programs through firewall if connection is secure

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-firewall

I have [setup an encrypted L2TP/IPsec connection using the built in settings in Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btYKT.png). I only want to allow certain applications (i.e., Chrome) to be able to access the network if I am connected to the VPN server. [Windows firewall has an option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK7XI.png) to only allow a connection for a specific program if it is secure.

However this approach has net me varying results. Chrome does not work at all when its rule is enabled and other program's rules do not seem to block their connections at all. I have used a packet viewer and I am pretty sure the connection is correctly encrypted so I'm guessing this is not the correct way to configure the firewall.

How can I restrict certain programs access to the internet if I am not connected to the VPN server?

Comment: Did you still allow DNS?

Comment: Wouldn't allowing DNS ruin the point of a VPN? Is there a way you can set a custom DNS server in the rules?

Comment: How do you expect a browser to know which server to connect to if you block him from obtaining that information? Why would it be a problem to allow DNS through that tunnel?